# Таймер обратного счёта, присвоение стилей элементам

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить код ниже, чтобы при достижении таймером нуля, тест прерывался и выходила надпись "Время вышло". Разное перепробовала, но он просто в минус уходит...
И как при неправильном ответе поменять стиль у кнопок и оставить их на экране, а потом уже переходить к следующему вопросу. Сейчас комментарий, к примеру, выводится уже над следующим вопросом, как притормозить этот процесс?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru-RU">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Тест на время</title>
    <style>
    body{
        font-family:verdana;
        color:#444;
    }
    #option1,#option2,#option3,#option4{
        display:none;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .kp{
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        color: #fff;
        background: #333333;
        padding: 4px 8px;
        border: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .nach{
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        color: #fff;
        background: #ff8000;
        padding: 4px 8px;
        border: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

     function mix(mixArray) {
          var index, valueIndex; 
          for (var i=0; i<=mixArray.length-1; i++) {
            index = Math.floor(Math.random()*i);
            valueIndex = mixArray[index];
            mixArray[index] = mixArray[i];
            mixArray[i] = valueIndex;
          }
          return mixArray;
        }
        //Массив вопросов и ответа
        var data_array = [
          ["Сколько сантиметров в метре?","10","1024","100","комм1",3],
          ["Перевод слова: Hello","Как дела?","Привет","Ты","комм2",2],
          ["Перевод слова: Dog","Собака","Кошка","Дерево","комм3",1],
          ["Сколько месяцев в году?","10","11","12","комм4",3],
          ["Перевод слова: Tree","Три","Собака","Дерево","комм5",3],
          ["Перевод слова: Wall","Стена","Дом","Башня","комм6",1],
        ];
    mix(data_array);
        var plus = 0;
        var time = 60;
        var cur_answer = 0;
        var count_answer = 3;

        function sec() {
            time=time-1;    
            document.getElementById('time').innerHTML=time + ' сек';
        }

        function check(num){

            if(num == 0){ 

                document.getElementById('option1').style.display='block';
                document.getElementById('option2').style.display='block';
                document.getElementById('option3').style.display='block';
                document.getElementById('question').style.display='block';

                document.getElementById('option1').innerHTML=data_array[cur_answer][1];
                document.getElementById('option2').innerHTML=data_array[cur_answer][2];
                document.getElementById('option3').innerHTML=data_array[cur_answer][3];
                document.getElementById('question').innerHTML=data_array[cur_answer][0];

                document.getElementById('start').style.display='none';


                var intervalID = setInterval(sec, 1000);

            }else{



                if( num ==  data_array[cur_answer][5]){
                    plus++;

                }   
                else{
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML="Неверно!" + [data_array[cur_answer][4]];
                }

                cur_answer++;




                if(cur_answer < count_answer){

                    document.getElementById('option1').innerHTML=data_array[cur_answer][1];
                    document.getElementById('option2').innerHTML=data_array[cur_answer][2];
                    document.getElementById('option3').innerHTML=data_array[cur_answer][3];
                    document.getElementById('question').innerHTML=data_array[cur_answer][0];

                }else{

                    document.getElementById('end').style.display='inline';
                    document.getElementById('time').id = 'stop';
                    document.getElementById('option1').style.display='none';
                    document.getElementById('option2').style.display='none';
                    document.getElementById('option3').style.display='none';
                    document.getElementById('question').style.display='none';
                    document.getElementById('end').style.display='inline';

                    var percent =  Math.round(plus/count_answer*100);               
                    var res = 'Плохо!';
                    if(percent>70) res = 'Хорошо!';
                    if(percent==100) res = 'Отлично!';

                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML='Правильных ответов: ' + plus + ' из ' + count_answer + ' (' + percent + '%)<br>' + res;
                }
                }

            }
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>

            <p style="font-size: 38px;font-weight: bold;padding-top: 2px;" id="time"></p>
            <p style="font-size: 38px;font-weight: bold;padding-top: 2px;" id="result"></p>
            <p style="font-size: 38px;font-weight: bold;padding-top: 2px;" id="vremya"></p>

            <p style="font-size: 38px;font-weight: bold;padding-top: 2px;" id="question"></p>

            <button onclick="check(1)" class="kp" id="option1"></button>

            <button onclick="check(2)" class="kp" id="option2"></button>

            <button onclick="check(3)" class="kp" id="option3"></button>

        </center><br>
        <center>
            <button id="start" class="kp" onclick="check(0)">Приступить к тесту</button>
            <script type="text/javascript"> var curent_url = document.URL; document.write("<a id='end' style='display: none;' class='nach' href='" + curent_url + "'>Начать сначала</a>"); </script>    
        </center><br><br>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

достаточно добавить в sec() перед изменением счётчика

```
if(time<0)
    clearInterval(intervalID);
```

объявить перед sec()

```
var intervalID;
```

и соответственно запускать таймер

```
 intervalID = setInterval(sec, 1000);
```

Насчёт остановки теста: я бы делал отдельный div с результатом и вопросами. При завершении таймера скрывать вопросы и показывать результат.

Comment: Почему-то вышло так, что таймер остановился не на 0, а на -2 секунды
Можете, пожалуйста, показать пример такого div?

Comment: А, всё, вышло :)